# How to transform a string (with a fixed delimiter) into an array to be appended to a JSON?

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace

I've some string inputted by user such as:

```
read -p "define module tags (example: TAG1, TAG2): " -r module_tags
if [ "$module tags" = "" ]; then module tags="TAG1, TAG2"; fi
```

which are tags separated by `,`

Than, I need to append these tags in a JSON array field:

```
{
    "modules": [
        {
            "tags": "<user-custom-tags>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would do it in this way:

```
args='.modules[0].tags = '$module_tags''

tmp=$(mktemp -u)

jq --indent 4 "$args" $plugin_file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" $plugin_file
```

But for this, I need to transform the input `TAG1, TAG2` to `[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]`

How would you do this?

Comment: Don't set `IFS` not needed. `temp=${tag##* }` (leaving `TAG2`) Then `temp=${tag%%,*}` (leaving `TAG1`) Use the comma to your advantage.

Comment: `module_tags_array` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for tag in $module_tags_array
```

This splits the value of `$module_tags_array` on `IFS`, i.e. you are looping over first `TAG1,` and then `TAG2`, not the list of tags.

What you are describing can easily be accomplished with

```
module_tags="[ $module_tags_array ]"
```

Notice also that the proper way to `echo` the value of the variable is with quotes:

```
echo "$module_tags"
```

unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the unquoted value.  See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

However, a more natural and obvious solution is to actually use an array to store the values.

```
tags=("TAG1" "TAG2")
printf "\"%s\", " "${tags[@]}" | sed 's/^/[/;s/, $/]/'
```

The `printf` produces a string like

```
"TAG1", "TAG2",
```

which we then massage into a JSON array expression with a quick bit of `sed` postprocessing.

Comment: `module_tags="[ $module_tags ]"` won't work. I'm appending (later, with jq) this array to a JSON. Each item need to be "TAG", and not TAG

Comment: So your actual question is how to add double quotes around the values, too? That's not actually obvious from your question.

Comment: @markzzz: State your entire question pipeline, right from where you get these inputs from and how _exactly_ would you like to transform it

Comment: what if I want to store the result on a var instead of printf? `myVar="${tags[@]}" | sed 's/^/[/;s/, $/]/'` does nothing...

Comment: You really need to read up on shell syntax. See also `printf -v`. Heaping on new requirements in comments is not really acceptable -- search and if you still need help ask a new question with all your requirements stated up front.

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you make a new answer? Or do I need a new question?

Comment: Replacing your question after you have received answers is not really acceptable. But too late now to go back I guess. In the future, just accept one of the answers (post one of your own if you like) and ask a new question.

Comment: Created a new question so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672838/how-to-add-double-quotes-around-the-values-separated-by-a-delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Not using bash*ism*, but using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line JSON parser:

```
<<< "TAG1, TAG2" jq -Rc 'split(", ")'
["TAG1","TAG2"]
```

`-R` is for raw input string
`-c` is for compact JSON output (on 1 line)
As expected, `split` function turns the input string into different part and put them into a JSON array.

Comment: how can "store" the result of that jq in a var? That just "print" to the terminal. I need to store the result...

Comment: use: `my_var=$(<<< "TAG1, TAG2" jq -Rc 'split(", ")')`

Comment: oliv the same of ceving solution: it doesn't work with `TAG1,TAG2` (i..e no space after `,`). How can I fix it? It should works the same for both cases

Comment: use: `split(", ?")` to add the optional space after the `,`

Comment: Tried `module_tags=$(<<< $module_tags jq -Rc 'split(", ?")')`, but its the same, doesn't work

Comment: please quote your bash variable `"$module_tags"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198517/discussion-between-markzzz-and-oliv).

Answer (score 0):

Use the ["Search and Replace"](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) feature of Bash's parameter expansion:

```
input="TAG1, TAG2"
output='[ "'${input//, /\", \"}'" ]'
printf "%s\n" "$output"
```

But be aware that this is not a proper way to quote.