# How to add double quotes around the values separated by a delimiter?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, split, jq

I take a string with values separated by `,`. I need to place "around them" the double quotes and, after each split, do a trim.

Here's my actual code:

```
input="TAG1, TAG2"
output='[ "'${input//, /\", \"}'" ]'
echo "$output"
```

which correctly display:

```
[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]
```

But:

1. It doesn't works if I use `input="TAG1,TAG2"` (i.e. no space after `,`)
2. If I use`input="   TAG1,   TAG2   "`, it keep spaces and don't trim each match. It should, for each item.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `jq` solution:

```
jq -cR '. | gsub("^ +| +$"; "") | split(" *, *"; "")' <<< "TAG1,TAG2"
["TAG1","TAG2"]

jq -cR '. | gsub("^ +| +$"; "") | split(" *, *"; "")' <<< "TAG1, TAG2"
["TAG1","TAG2"]

jq -cR '. | gsub("^ +| +$"; "") | split(" *, *"; "")' <<< "   TAG1,       TAG2     "
["TAG1","TAG2"]
```

**PS:** Remove `-c` if you want pretty `json` output.

---

You may also use `awk`:

```
cat comma.csv
```

```
BEGIN {
   FS = " *, *"
   OFS=", "
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      gsub(/^ *| *$/, "", $i)
      $i = "\"" $i "\""
   }

   print "[ " $0 " ]"
}
```

and use it as:

```
awk -f comma.csv <<< "TAG1, TAG2"
[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]

awk -f comma.csv <<< "TAG1,TAG2"
[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]

awk -f comma.csv <<< "   TAG1,   TAG2   "
[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]
```

---

**`sed` solution:**

```
sed 's/^ */[ "/; s/ *$/" ]/; s/ *, */", "/g' <<< "       TAG1,        TAG2     "
[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]    

sed 's/^ */[ "/; s/ *$/" ]/; s/ *, */", "/g' <<< "TAG1,TAG2"
[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]

sed 's/^ */[ "/; s/ *$/" ]/; s/ *, */", "/g' <<< "TAG1 , TAG2"
[ "TAG1", "TAG2" ]
```

Comment: `awk` is present on every unix, Linux, OSX system by default

Comment: This write on a file. I Need to write to a var, as in the example. Can you post code that do it?

Comment: No, this doesn't write to a file. To store output in a variable use: `var=$(awk -f comma.csv <<< "   TAG1,   TAG2   ")`

Comment: I have added a `jq` and `sed` solutions also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't what does "trim" mean, I assume whitespaces can be safely ignored.

So first let's read the input into an array. Read items separated by spaces or comma.

```
input="        TAG1        ,      TAG2        "
IFS=', ' read -r -a input <<<"$input"
```

Then create the `output`: first output array elements quoetd with `"` on separate newlines, then join them with a comma, add leading `[` and trailing `]`:

```
output="[ $(printf '"%s"\n' "${input[@]}" | paste -sd,) ]"
echo "$output"
```